# Extrema of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I have to find the extrema of:
$$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\left(2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}\right)$$
I calculated $a_1= \frac{1}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n} a_n=(-2,2)$.
Then
$$\left|\left(2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}\right)\right|<2$$

thus I think that $\sup=2$ and $\inf=-2$ but I am not sure how to demonstrate it.

**My attempt:**

I separate $a_n$ into $a_{2k}$ and $a_{2k-1}$, then:

$$a_{2k}<2 \Rightarrow 1\left(2-\frac{2k+2}{2^{2k}}\right)<2, \text{ true for } k>-1$$

$$a_{2k-1}>-2 \Rightarrow -1\left(2-\frac{2k+1}{2^{2k-1}}\right)>-2, \text{ true for } k>-\frac1{2}$$

So I know that $a_n$ is bounded.

I tried to demonstrate that $\sup=2$ and $\inf=-2$ by doing the following:

$$a_{2k}>2-\varepsilon \Rightarrow 1\left(2-\frac{2k+2}{2^{2k}}\right)>2-\varepsilon$$

$$a_{2k-1}<-2+\varepsilon \Rightarrow -1\left(2-\frac{2k+1}{2^{2k-1}}\right)<-2+\varepsilon,$$
but I can't solve those inequalities. Is this one the right approach?

**EDIT**

**Another attempt:** (Thanks to G Cab's answer)

$$-b_n<a_n<b_n$$

where $b_n=\left(2-\frac{n+2}{2^n}\right)$.

$-b_n$ is decreasing and the limit is $-2$, and as the sequence is decreasing, $-2=\inf(-b_n)$.

$b_n$ is increasing and the limit is $2$, and as the sequence is increasing, $2=\sup(b_n)$. Thus

$$-2<-b_n<a_n<b_n<2$$

and $\sup(a_n)=2$ and $\inf(a_n)=-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(x) = 2 - {{x + 2} \over {2^{\,x} }}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad y(0) = 0  \cr 
  & f'(x) = {{\ln 2\left( {x + 2} \right) - 1} \over {2^{\,x} }}  \cr 
  & 0 < f'(x) = \quad  \Rightarrow \quad {1 \over {\ln 2}} - 2 \approx  - 0.557 < x \cr} 
$$
so $f(n)$ is increasing for $0 \le n$.

Thus the alternating sequence $(-1)^{n+1}f(n)$ is clearly bounded to stay between $\pm 2$.

I am not a theorist, but I think that a *formal* demonstration should develop along these lines
(maybe somebody more expert can help and put it in right terms)

Given that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a_{\,n}  \in Q = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n + 1} f(n) \hfill \cr 
  \left\{ {a_{\,n} } \right\} = \left\{ {a_{\,2n} } \right\} \cup \left\{ {a_{\,2n + 1} } \right\}\quad \left| {\;\left\{ {a_{\,2n} } \right\} \cap \left\{ {a_{\,2n + 1} } \right\} = \emptyset } \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } a_{\,2n}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2n + 1} f(2n) =  - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\; \to \;\infty } f(x) =  - 2  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } a_{\,2n + 1}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2n + 2} f(2n + 1) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\; \to \;\infty } f(x) = 2 \cr} 
$$
and having demonstrated that $f(x)$ is increasing
$$
f(n - 1) < f(n) < f(n + 1)
$$
that means
$$
\eqalign{
  &  - 2 < a_{\,2n} \, \le a_{\,0}  =  0  \cr 
  & 1/2 = a_{\,1}  \le a_{\,2n + 1} \, < 2 \cr} 
$$
and therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & \inf \left\{ {a_{\,n} } \right\} = \min \left( {\inf \left\{ {a_{\,2n} } \right\},\inf \left\{ {a_{\,2n + 1} } \right\}\;} \right) =  - 2  \cr 
  & \sup \left\{ {a_{\,n} } \right\} = \max \left( {\sup \left\{ {a_{\,2n} } \right\},\sup \left\{ {a_{\,2n + 1} } \right\}\;} \right) = 2 \cr} 
$$

Comment: I already proved that the sequence is bounded to stay between $\pm 2$.
I have to prove that $-2$ is the greatest lower bound and $+2$ is the smallest upper bound

Comment: @Lorenzo:  but, since $y(n)$ is **increasing**, $y(0)=0$ and $2$ is its limit for $n \to \infty$, then what  more ?

Comment: Now I got It, thank you

Comment: I edited the question, could you please tell me if the new attempt is right?

Answer (score -1):

I think, you are right because $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_{2n}=-2$$ and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_{2n-1}=2$$ and use your work.

Comment: I don't understand how can I prove that

Comment: Do I consider $a_n$ as the two separate sequences, $a_{2n-1}$ and $a_{2n}$ and go from there?

Comment: Because you got that $|a_n|<2$ and since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}|a_n|=2,$ we get your answer. By the way, I think it's obvious that $\frac{n+2}{2^n}\rightarrow0$.